# How to render HTML element property defined inside angular component method returning a string?

Tags: angular

I have an angular method that returns a string.

```js
private getRangeOriginsText(tags: string[], ipRange: string): string {
  return `ipRange is part of the IP range <a routerLink="/route/ip-ranges/"> test </a>`, 
}
```

However my component renders the HTML  link as text, instead of the element (see below).
[image]

How can I get the actual  link to render?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `[innerHTML]` this property allow us to set HTML content passing it as a string.

Here is an example.

```
<div [innerHTML]="getRangeOriginsText(['sometag'], '111')"></div>
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: is there no way to return the HTML markup in the method itself?